# Bootstrap - Cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am relatively new to front end design work, building a fake e-commerce website for practice, and am having trouble with bootstrap lining. If I inspect the html on the page my cards technically line up correctly, but when displayed they are not equal. I understand that content of some is longer than others but shouldn't bootstraps group card-deck fix this issue (according to the docs at least) The code is as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class='row p-3'>
    <div class="card-deck">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name|title }}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${{ product.price }}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">{{ product.history }}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this would be my css:

```
body {
    background: #fef8f5;
}

.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card {
    border: 4px solid #eb5d1e;
    margin: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Here is a screen shot showing that they do not line up correctly when displayed.
[image: example here]

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? I have been searching for hours and every single thing I have tried does not seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Haha no unfortunately not, and funny enough it is the same one by me but I thought I might ask again when more people are awake in the US:)

Comment: I appreciate the advice but I would have to disagree, especially when I can just easily delete the question. Why have a question sit there that only was viewed approximately 10 times for weeks on end when you could technically ask the same question again at a more appropriate time? There are not many people who go looking for such unanswered questions in their free time, I would bet most just look at the popular ones or bountied ones for a few pages and stop.

Comment: Rather than using `card-deck`, try [grid cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#grid-cards) and add `h-100` to the card `div`.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I experimented with adding just h-100 and then adjusting some other settings to the card div to center everything